# Application crashes on Windows 2008 Server R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I am trying to run an application on a clean installation of Windows 2008 Server R2. When I start it I get ObjectWindowsException with the following error: "Create fail for windows mStatica 3, 0, TSDIDecFrame". The same app runs on Windows 7 without problems (it requires admin rights; I tried run as administrator on WS2008 too). Is it something that can be solved by installing some piece of software that is missing on WS 2008 Server R2 or is it to generic to be asked here and I should contact the app vendor? I cannot find any helpful info on the Internet.

Comment: What the heck is Windows 2008 RT2?

Comment: Windows 2008 R2. Typo

Comment: What app? Try installing desktop experience - windows smells like it may use somt stuff normally not there on windows server. THen tell us what application and check the application compatibility matrix. Is it supported on 2008 R2? What does support say (yes, they are not useless - at least they know what applicaiton you talk about, we do not).

Comment: I contacted them while writing this message and got the response quite quickly. They only say that they support Win7 and do not support server editions...I have a hunch that it could work, I just need to install/configure something...

Comment: `TSDIDecFrame` is a call to a window UI element, which may not be present by default in Server 2008 R2.  So, as TomTom suggests, try installing the Desktop Experience feature, and if that doesn't work, try running it in Compatibility mode for Windows 7, and see if you get any joy.

Comment: Disabling DEP helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AND YES. I MANAGED. It was caused by Data Execution Prevention.
The following command followed by a restart helped: `bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOff` (run cmd as administrator)